# Mongodb filter data on multiple levels

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, laravel-mongodb

I have a collection of employees containing employee data and some events with start and end times...
I want to query data in order to get a subset of a specific employee's events based on the start and the end of events.

```
employees = [
  {
    _id: 5,
    events: [
      {
        start:5,
        end:10
      },
      {
        start:15,
        end:20
      },
      {
        start:21,
        end:26
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 6,
    events: [
      {
        start:3,
        end:10
      },
      {
        start:15,
        end:22
      },
      {
        start:23,
        end:26
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

The desired result:
a list of events with start greater than x and end less than y for an employee with _id of z.

for now I am trying:

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  { $match: {'_id': 5}},
  { $unwind: '$events'}, 
  { $match: {'events.start': 2}
]);
```

but still I cant filter the subset using $gt/$lt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": 5,
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$events"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "events.start": {
        $gte: 15
      },
      "events.end": {
        $lte: 250
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working example for it. https://mongoplayground.net/p/smUNCxfzC_N